# Why is the "Game Over" text not displayed?

Tags: python, pygame

I have this code, and when I click <kbd>ESC</kbd>, I don't see "Game Over". The program waits for two seconds and closes without displaying text.
Pygame 1.9.6

What am I doing wrong?

```py
run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            pygame.quit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                lead_x_change = -block_size
                lead_y_change = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                lead_x_change = block_size
                lead_y_change = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                lead_x_change = 0
                lead_y_change = -block_size
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                lead_x_change = 0
                lead_y_change = block_size
            elif event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                run = False

    game_display.fill(white)
    lead_x += lead_x_change
    lead_y += lead_y_change
    pygame.draw.rect(game_display, black, [lead_x, lead_y, width, height])
    pygame.display.update()

    clock.tick()

draw_text_middle("Game Over", 40, (0, 0, 0, 255), game_display)
pygame.display.update()
pygame.time.delay(2000)
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: May be put a break point on the line `draw_text_middle("Game Over", 40, (0, 0, 0, 255), game_display)` and look what's going on !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've to remove the `pygame.quit()` call from the event loop. [`pygame.quit()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html#pygame.quit) uninitialize all pygame modules. After calling this function, nothing can be drawn any further calls to any pygame instructions will cause an exception.
I recommend to process the pygame events by [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) before [`.delay`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.delay) the application. This allows pygame to handle internal actions:

```py
run = True
while run:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            # pygame.quit() <---------- delete

    # [...]

draw_text_middle("Game Over", 40, (0, 0, 0, 255), game_display)
pygame.display.update()

pygame.event.pump()

pygame.time.delay(2000)
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: it didn't help(

Comment: When I click ESC, program waits for 2 seconds and then I can see "Game Over" a few milliseconds before closing

Comment: @user3418889 Clear the event loop before `.delay` see the answer.